# NSMutableArray behaviour with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

With ARC enabled when adding an object (e.g. object X) to an NSMutableArray, if that object X is changed directly elsewhere in code, should the "copy" inside the NSMutableArray also be updated?

Is the NSMutableArray just referencing the pointer of the original object?

Comment: What "copy"?  When you add an object to an NSArray or NSDictionary you're adding the "original".  The only thing that's copied is the pointer.  This is the way it's always been, ARC or no ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a `copy` then no. If you've added it as a reference then yes. It's just a pointer to an object so any changes to your object will apply to the object reference in the array.

Don't be confused by the NSMutable part of the array. The same thing happens with a normal NSArray: if you change the object, then the array will have a reference to the changed object. The mutable part only applies to the array, not the objects in the array.

Comment: Thanks, so once i've done this: [myArray addObject:X]; I've added as a pointer and it will update.  thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Not when you add like this :

```
[marray addObject:[object2 copy]];
```

But when you add it like this (as a reference), it will get updated:

```
[marray addObject:object2];
```